# Ordering dataframe by month-year date column

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, zoo

I have a dataframe df:

```
date        values
Apr-15        86
Apr-16        80
Apr-17        60
Aug-14        88
Aug-15        52
Aug-16        76
```

My desired output should be :

```
 date        values
Aug-14        88
Apr-15        86
Aug-15        52
Apr-16        80
Aug-16        76
Apr-17        60
```

My date format is different so I am unable to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the column into date object by pasting an arbitrary date value and then `order`

```
df[order(as.Date(paste0("1-", df$date), "%d-%b-%y")), ]

#    date values
#4 Aug-14     88
#1 Apr-15     86
#5 Aug-15     52
#2 Apr-16     80
#6 Aug-16     76
#3 Apr-17     60
```

Or using `zoo::as.yearmon` which will not require date

```
df[order(zoo::as.yearmon(df$date, "%b-%y")), ]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Apr-15", "Apr-16", 
"Apr-17", "Aug-14", "Aug-15", "Aug-16"), class = "factor"), values = c(86L, 
80L, 60L, 88L, 52L, 76L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
df[with(df,order(gsub("[^0-9]","",date))),]
```